# How can i concatenate FirstName and LastName in xaml using markup extension method to show full name of user

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to concatencate the firstName and lastName of the user using xaml markup extension.
Here is the code.

> **Contact**

```
 public class Contact
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string Phone { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public bool Blocked { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is the contactService for populating the data

> **ContactService**

```
  public class ContactService
  {
      public readonly List<Contact> Contact = new List<Contact>()
      {
          new Contact
          {
              Id = 1,
              FirstName = "Malik",
              LastName = "Usama",
              Phone = "123456",
              Email = "abc@gmail.com",
              Blocked = true
          }
      };
  }
```

> **MainPage.Xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    private ICollection<Contact> _contacts;
    private readonly ContactService _contactService = new ContactService();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView.ItemsSource = _contactService.Contact;
    }
}
```

> **MainPage.Xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You'd be better off using a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter as @canton7 said, or you just add another Property inside your Contact class which concatenate the properties for you:

```
public string NameView
{
  get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";}
}
```

and then, you can easily bind to your `NameView`-Property. Keep in mind, that you need to trigger `NotifyPropertyChanged` if you use data changes.

A converter would be looks like this:

```
public class NameConverter : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    Contact contact = (Contact)value;
    return $"{contact.FirstName} {contact.LastName}";
  }

    ...
}
```

and in your XAML just use it:

```
xmlns:base="clr-namespace:<add your namespace here>"

<ResourceDictionary>
    <base:Name x:Key="nameConv" />
</ResourceDictionary>

<TextCell Text="{Binding Path= ., Converter={StaticResource nameConv}}"></TextCell>
```

Comment: Sorry what does the . signafy I am trying to bind this in a picker

Comment: @csharpdude77 its used to bind to the current source itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-path-syntax (see last part). Quote:" `Text="{Binding}" is equivalent to Text="{Binding Path=.}"`". Because we have more than one parameter we need to define the path exclusive.